# pygame.midi Exception: PortMidi: `Insufficient memory'

Tags: python, pygame, midi

Im trying to setup pygame.midi to communicate with my midi input device (usb)
but i keep getting

" Exception: PortMidi: `Insufficient memory' "

and if i retry without reinitializing i get" Exception: PortMidi: `Host error'"

it seems very simple, i just copied code from this guy:
https://github.com/kushalbhabra/pyMidi/blob/master/src/test.py
which i found from this youtube vid:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhNow4cUMV8

to try out how it works, but i can't seem to get passed this simple error.

my code looks like this, and fails at last line:

```
import pygame.midi

pygame.init()

pygame.midi.init()
input_id = pygame.midi.get_default_input_id()
i = pygame.midi.Input( input_id )
```

my device is recognised. if i insert

```
print pygame.midi.get_device_info(input_id)
```

i get "('MMSystem', 'nanoKEY', 1, 0, 0)"

i use python 2.7 32 bit on 64 bit win7 if that matters

Answer (score 3):

I'd the same problem on Windows 7, Python 2.7.8, pygame-1.9.2a0.win32.

I tried to install pygame-1.9.1.win32 and it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad It does - the last line - try downgrading pygame to 1.9.1 instead.

Comment: Worked for me nicely